# Авторизация на сайте REST API

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. 
Используя REST API я передал с EditText данные для входа, логин и пароль - авторизовался на сайте.
Вопрос, как мне определить что "я это я", ну то есть, в php я бы это сделал условием

```
if ($user['id'] == $anketa['id']) {
Я владелец этой страницы
}
```

И как мне не терять авторизацию в приложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возвращайте с php себе результат если удачно то true и записывайте в Preference. Вот хороший гайд на тему [Preference](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html)